# What happens to phase after wavefunction collapse?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Suppose an initial quantum state $\psi = a_1\phi_1 + a_2\phi_2 + ... + a_n\phi_n$, where $\phi_i$ is the eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of some measurement operator. Post-measurement, we will find the system in state $\phi_i$ with probability $|a_i|^2$.

What happens to the phase post-measurement? The principle that immediate subsequent measurements should always return the same value would be satisfied no matter the resulting phase. We might find the system in any state $b\phi_i$, so long as $|b|^2=1$. I am sure the postulates of quantum mechanics specify something about this, but I haven't managed to find any text that addresses it. What should $b$ be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, states are represented by *rays* in Hilbert space, or more accurately, the space of states is *projective Hilbert space* - for example, for a finite dimensional system, the space is $H_n / \sim \ \cong \mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$, where for $u, v \in H_n$, $u \sim v$ if $u = \alpha w$ for some non-zero complex number $\alpha$.

Now usually we prefer to work with the plain Hilbert space rather than the projective one, choosing to impose the quotient whenever useful - simply because we have many more useful tools at our disposal while working with Hilbert spaces.

However, you must always remember that the actual space of states is the projective Hilbert space, which means that the statement "We might find the system in any state $b\phi_i$ as long as $|b|^2 = 1$" is meaningless, because there aren't separate states $b\phi_i$ - neither is it that all these states are the "same" - the real reason is that there is only *one* state $\phi_i$ in projective Hilbert space.

Comment: There is an important conceptual distinction that must be made. There are two different entities that are sometimes called "states", which seems to have caused confusion in the whole discussion. One entity, the one you are talking about in your answer, is an element of the projective Hilbert space (let's call that the physical state for now). The other entity, the one the question was really about I think, is the mathematical object that enters in the standard Schrodinger equation. That object is an element of the regular Hilbert space, and most people, and the OP, refer to it as the state...

Comment: … Let's call that object the standard state for now, until we sort out the terminology, and to distinguish it from the physical state. The crucial difference between the two is revealed starkly by the fact that it is specifically the **standard state**, NOT the physical state, that we are talking about when we say that **the energy eigenstate evolves by a multiplicative phase factor**. It is the standard state that we most commonly work with, most often call simply "state", most often use in linear combinations and inner products etc. And for that object the phase is certainly important.

Answer (score 2):

Wavefunction collapse is just a fiction that we employ because it would be a hassle to describe measurements realistically as entanglement of the observer with the thing being observed, with decoherence.

Phase in quantum mechanics isn't an observable. You can only determine the phase of something relative to something else. The phase $b_1$ of the state after you've measured the system to be in state 1 doesn't have any meaning by itself. You would need to compare it with some other phase, such as the phase $b_2$ of the system that's entangled with a person who measured it to be in state 2. If you could do this, then it would be meaningful to say, for example, that $\operatorname{arg}(b_2/b_1)$ has some value. To do this, you would have to do something like measuring interference between the person in state 1 and the person in state 2. But the whole reason that collapse is a good approximation is that decoherence makes it impossible for us to detect this kind of interference, so that person 1 might as well stop keeping track of the existence of the other possibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Post-measurement, we will find the system in state $\phi_i$ with probability $|a_i|^2$.

Almost, the correct final state is $$a_i\phi_i,$$ it's just the result of applying the projection operator. If we wish, we can then normalize it to $$\frac{a_i}{|a_i|}\phi_i,$$ but we should only do it if we know we won't be comparing or superposing it with other states. When we normalize it, we divide it by a **real** number, which does not remove the phase. The overall phase is not important **only** if we don't plan to compare/superpose the state with other states.

One way to see that the final state is $a_i\phi_i$, or if we wish its normalized cousin with the phase intact, is to imagine first that all but the $i$th coefficients $a_j$ are 0 and consider the overall post-measurement state of system+apparatus. By continuity, immediately post-measurement the overall state is exactly the same as immediately pre-measurement (we are talking about instantaneous collapses in this question). Therefore we should assign the post-measurement state **of the system** to also be what it was immediately pre-measurement, $a_i\phi_i$. Anything else would be a bizarre  ad hoc unnecessary step.

For the general case, with non-zero other coefficients, the same should be true by linearity, because collapsing the state just means keeping only one of the resulting branches.

Comment: But do we end up in state $\phi$ or $i\phi$?

Comment: $\phi_i$, as you said, not $i\phi_i$. The phase does matter... well, sort of... more precisely, we need to keep track of the phases, in order to keep track of relative phases. No reason to deliberatelly drop them when we are sure we don't need them anymore, though @NiharKarve is correct that technically you _can_ (not _must_) drop them.

Comment: @retracted darn, I realized I made a silly mistake in my answer. Not about the phase being unimportant, it's definitely important to keep track of it (for example, we don't say that it's incorrect or meaningless to say that **an energy eigenstate evolves by a multiplicative factor $e^ {i\omega t}$!**, which is what the view expressed in the other answer seems to imply)...

Comment: …My mistake was that for some reason my brain decided that the coefficients $a_i$ are real, which is of course not necessarily true. So the correct final state is $a_i\phi_i$, it's just the result of applying the projection operator. If we wish, we can normalize it, although we certainly don't have to, and we can only do it if we know we won't be comparing it with other states. When we normalize it, we divide it by a **real** number, which does not remove the phase. The overall phase is not important **only** if we don't compare/superpose the state with other states,

Comment: @ReasonMeThis If we're being pedantic, an energy eigen*ket* evolves by a multiplicative phase factor, but the *state* to which that ket corresponds does not evolve at all (or evolves trivially, if you prefer). The distinction is typically not operationally important, but it does have the benefit of being true.

Comment: @j.Murray perhaps under some definition of the word state that's true, but most of the time people refer to the mathematical object that enters in the Schrodinger equation as the “state". That's the sense in which the author of the question was using it. Under that definition the energy eigenstate does evolve.

Comment: @ReasonMeThis I know, see e.g. [my answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/545402/156895).

Comment: Oh, then we don't really disagree too much. I would probably prefer to use the term "physical state" for what you call "state", to avoid confusion, and to be able to continue using the term "state" to refer to the above mentioned mathematical object, since it is that object that we usually manipulate in our equations, and we would like a nice short common term for it.

Comment: @ReasonMeThis Would it still end up in $a_i \phi$ if $|a_i|^2 < 1$?

Comment: You have a minor typo there, you forgot one index, but modulo that - yes. Of course it won't be normalized then, so as I mentioned in my answer you can then (and probably should for most purposes, although it's not some absolute requirement) normalize it. This question turned out to be far more subtle and interesting than I initially gave it credit for, and of course i botched my original version of the answer. The crucial point however is the stuff I put in bold above. I expressed things even better in my comment below the accepted answer, check it out if you haven't seen it yet.